# getRequestDispatcher(" ").forward does not work in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2

I have following codes in my app which is using JSF 2.0

```
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                    .getRequest();
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
......

try {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("SomePage.xhtml").forward(request, response);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But when ever the line ..

```
 request.getRequestDispatcher("SomePage.xhtml").forward(request, response);
```

is executed I'm getting the following exception...

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    at javax.faces.component.AttachedObjectListHolder.restoreState(AttachedObjectListHolder.java:165)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1432)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl$1.visit(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:265)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151)
```

Due to some appilcation constaints I can not use the

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect();
```

method..

Is it a JSF 2.0 bug??

Comment: Okay it seems that there are some JSF life cycle method needed to be called before doing the forward as I was able to do the foward with the normal JSF navigation. Any idea which methods??

Answer (score 1):

I never tried to send a redirect this way because this is not the standard solution for navigation in JSF2.

Here are some methods that will work correctly in a JSF 2.0 environment:

**1. Specify the redirect command in the navigation link**

Attach `?faces-redirect=true` to your navigation and this should do the job.

```
public String someAction(){
    // Logic here
    return "newPage" + "?faces-redirect=true"
}

<h:form id = "form">
    <h:inputText>...</h:inputText>
    <h:commandButton action = "#{controller.someAction}" />
</h:form>
```

After processing the Login in the `someAction` the navigation flow will be redirected to `newPage.xhtml`. All you have to do is to correctly call the action from your UI Form.

**2. Specify the redirect through external context**

This method is closer to what you are looking for:

```
public void someAction(){
    // Logic here
    try{
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("newPage");
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: @BalusC Thank you! I saw the `.redirect()` there and that mislead me somehow

Answer (score 0):

First of all, whenever you need to use `javax.servlet.*` classes inside a JSF managed bean, then changes are big that you're doing things the wrong way or unnecessarily overcomplicated. Keep this in mind for the next time you need to a add a `import javax.servlet...;` line.

As to your concrete problem, in your particular case, you should just be returning the view ID in order to perform a forward.

```
public String someAction() {
    // ...

    return "SomePage";
}
```

An alternative is `ExternalContext#dispatch()` method, but this is also unnecessarily overcomplicated.